# Ruby: CLI progress bar with open-uri

Tags: ruby, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I'm trying to experiment with the open-uri and want to make a Command line interface progress bar.

I've going over the documentation for OpenURI::OpenRead where is has a progress bar code sample.

```
pbar = nil
open('latest.zip', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.print open('http://wordpress.org/latest.zip',
    :content_length_proc => lambda { |t|
    if t && 0 < t
      pbar = ProgressBar.new("...", t)
      pbar.file_transfer_mode
    end
    },

    :progress_proc => lambda {|s|
      pbar.set s if pbar
    }).read
end
```

but I'm can keep getting the following error:

```
zip_dowloader.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': uninitialized constant ProgressBar (NameError)
```

Comment: Did you require `progress_bar` (or whatever the name is)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gem install progressbar`

Then add:

```
require 'progressbar'
```

to the top of your script.

Or, in a bundler-enabled project, add:

```
gem 'progressbar'
```

to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks, That fixed it. I just assumed that because it was used in the documentation, it was already part of ruby.